# XSLT for-each-group from variable does not work

Tags: grouping, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

for-each-group from XSLT 2.0 works as expected from a file but not from a variable.

Have this file:
~$ cat test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <delimiter/>
    <c>A</c><c>B</c>
  <delimiter/>
    <c>C</c>
</root>
```

Using stylesheet for grouping this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
  encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

<xsl:template match="*">

  <!-- variable not used for file test -->
  <xsl:variable name="fields">
    <root>
      <delimiter/>
      <c>A</c><c>B</c>
      <delimiter/>
      <c>C</c>
    </root>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="delimiter">
    <field>
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:value-of select="self::c"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </field>
  </xsl:for-each-group>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the result I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<field>AB</field>
<field>C</field>
```

Trying to group the variable name="fields" with:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$fields/*" group-starting-with="delimiter">
```

I get the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<field/>
```

Why does for-each-group works on a file but not from a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `fields` is a document-node(), you can define the type of the variable to be element()

```
<xsl:variable name="fields" as="element()">
    <root>
        <delimiter/>
        <c>A</c><c>B</c>
        <delimiter/>
        <c>C</c>
    </root>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: It's as simple as that. But you have to know :) Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ingo, as an alternative you could adapt the path in the `select` to `<xsl:for-each-group select="$fields/root/*" group-starting-with="delimiter">`

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, it works too, thanks. Step by step I learn the details of xslt. It means with selecting `$fields/*` I will get implicit a document node, the other way I will get implicit an element node?. But from now on I will always specify the type for stability. For those who are interested in the basics like me here are the links I found: [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#temporary-trees) [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/). But does this mean I only can query variables as element nodes?

Comment: Given your initial declaration `<xsl:variable name="fields"><root>...</root></xsl:variable>` the variable holds a document node containing a root element named `root` containing the other elements. And then of course, to select the other elements in your `for-each-group` you need the path `$fields/root/*`, much like you would need that path if you had used e.g. `<xsl:variable name="fields" select="doc('fields.xml')"/>` to load a normal XML document.

Comment: On the other hand, given the declaration `<xsl:variable name="fields" as="element()"><root>...</root></xsl:variable>`, the variable holds an element node named `root` directly and to select its child elements for your `for-each-group` you then only need `$fields/*`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks, that's all very helpful for understanding. But sorry for annoying ;-) On the other hand it means that `<xsl:template match="*">` always select an element?

Comment: `<xsl:template match="*">` matches any element. I would suggest you start with an introduction to XSLT and XPath, there are good books and courses like https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1